# generating integer ID for PK- MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to implement a button on my HTML form. It has to generate integer ID to be assigned to the entity on form.

This ID is actually primary key for the table representing the entity on form.

My issue is - I have to show Id to the user before user adds an entity, so I can not use auto_increment field or Max ID available during insert. Also, I have to avoid same ID taken by 2 concurrent users and so ensure unique IDs. At the same time, I also want to avoid unused IDs generated and taken up by users with no records added for those IDs (I know disabling the button after using it once would cause minimal IDs wasted).

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to meet all those constraints.

Comment: you can do an empty insert (only way to "reserve" that id for a specific form) and delete empty records with a cron job after. Otherwise the ID that your form gets will be a guess of what the PK will be

Comment: The best way, without wanting to sound rude, is to scrap that idea and forget about it. Shove it in a trash bin and light it on fire. It's awful from many perspectives and like @Barmar noted - most likely without a proper way to implement.

Comment: It is possible to do it with the help of additional table, but it make your life more difficult to implement, but if you still want this feature badly, I can write answer how to do it with additional table to help hold the reserved ID.

Comment: @invisal Is right, it could be done in the way he is hinting. However if you cannot think of the solution on your own its unlikely you could write and mantain the code to manage such a complex solution without getting yourself in a complete mess.

Comment: Actually In our running system, we do have DB procedures for few Sybase tables looking for Blank IDs, then for a heavily loaded table we run a countserver process, but I thought there might be better ideas or something I don't know exists in MySQL but not in Sybase.